# Return number of edges of each vertex in a digraph (jgrapht)

Tags: java, processing, jgrapht, digraphs

I have a digraph created using:

```
    public static DirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);

 void setup() { 

  Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
  Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);
  directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);

  Point mySecondPoint = new Point(x, y);
  Point mySecondNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);
  directedGraph.addVertex(mySecondPoint);
  directedGraph.addVertex(mySecondNextPoint);
  directedGraph.addEdge(mySecondPoint, mySecondNextPoint);

System.out.println("#vertices: "+ directedGraph.vertexSet());

}

 public static class Point {

  public int x;
  public int y;

  public  Point(int x, int y) 
  {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  @Override
    public String toString() {
    return ("[x="+x+" y="+y+"]");
  }

  @Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.x;
    hash = 71 * hash + this.y;
    return hash;
}



@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) 
{
    if (this == other)
       return true;

    if (!(other instanceof Point))
       return false;

    Point otherPoint = (Point) other;
    return otherPoint.x == x && otherPoint.y == y;
}
}
```

I would like to get the number of outwards edges per vertex using:

```
directedGraph.outDegreeOf()
```

but I don't want to do it vertex per vertex (this is a simple code to make it easier to go through it, in my whole program I have many more vertices) and I'd like to go through the vertex set and return the number of outwards edges for each vertex of the set automatically, no matter how many vertices there are.

How should I proceed to do this ?

(I use processing which is based on java)

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "but I don't want to do it vertex per vertex"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [JGrapht API](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/).

The [`DirectedGraph`](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/Graph.html) interface contains a [`vertexSet()`](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/Graph.html#vertexSet--) function. You can use this to iterate over the vertexes you've added, and you can get the `outDegreeValue()` of each one:

```
for(Point p : directedGraph.vertexSet()){
   int degree = directedGraph.outDegreeOf(p);
   System.out.println("Degree of " p.toString() + ": " + degree);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if `DirectedGraph` stores this information inherently or not,  but you can easily store this information while adding the edge, by using a hasmap.

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer>  outEdgesMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
```

you are doing

```
directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
```

after this also do

```
outEdgesMap.put(myPoint,outEdgesMap.getOrDefault(myPoint,0)+1);
```

Just to be clear, it will be

```
directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
outEdgesMap.put(myPoint,outEdgesMap.getOrDefault(myPoint,0)+1);
```

So your `directedGraph.outDegreeOf()` will be

```
        for(Integer i : outEdgesMap.keySet()){
             sout(i+ " : " +outEdgesMap.get(i) );
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! does it work after if I do: System.out.println(outEdgedMap);  to have displayed the number of outwards edges for each vertex ?

Comment: No, I added that part also.

Comment: is outEdgesMap part of the jgrapht library ? Can't find anything about it and my program doesn't seem to recognize it. Do I need to define it ?

Comment: It's not a part of library. It's a simple HashMap, you have to define it. I added that.